# Change table data according to cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to do an attendance list for 3 shifts with different leader, I suppose there is an easy way to change list of personnel according to a cell (with dropdown) but I can't manage to find how.

[Please see this image for checking attendace list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUROe.png)

In the image above you can see in Cell B2 the Leader name an then there is the list of personnel below. I want that list to change when I change the Leader, based on other tabels found on another sheet.

[Personnel lists by Leader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxWUz.png)

I hope it isn't so much trobule, I'm sorry if the post doens't complies with posting rules, I will kndfully edit it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Data Validation under the Data Tab to create a dropdown list in A1, Then you would want to setup in each cell using a formula like something like this
`=IF($A$1="Jane Doe",Sheet2!C8,IF($A$1="John Smith",Sheet3!C8,Sheet4!C8))`
If you put this formula in cell c8 you can drag it across the table to copy it respectively for each cell.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I was trying to look for a more automated method with VBA, at the end I decided to make a userform with a dependant combobox.